# Execute remote batch file from within a C# forms application

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I am working on a VPN dialer that will execute a login script when the connection is successfull using the following method.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\serverName\NETLOGON\Script Test.cmd";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

The batch file execute properly according to the logging methods in the batch file, but the drives are not acctualy mapped for the user to use.  Other batch files tested (local & remote) have the same result.

I am assuming this has something to do with the application domain or UAC. The finished application will run on Viata/7 and is being tested on Windows 7.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped Drives are stored in a users profile. Which typically gets loaded when the person logs in. The most common way to get access to profile associated resources is to impersonate the user.

There is a relationally poor (PInvoke) example of how to do this here: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4

But generally using mapped drives from a script is asking for trouble. IMHO :)

Hope that helps,

Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan,

A point of clarification.  I am attempting this using WinForms, will the Web Security namespaces work in this situation?

Comment: No it will not. You will need pretty close to Domain Admin level permission.

If I were you I would avoid using mapped drives in this context. They are notoriously difficult to get right

Comment: Actually you could try using subst instead. It does the same as mapping the drive but allows you to do it at the command line. 

You will still, however, need to know what drives are mapped where beforehand.

Comment: I adapted the example to WinForms and all worked well.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any exception happened. I see catch(exception ex) swallows you exception.

Comment: Yea I droped that out for readability. Any exception is displayed in a textBox on the form, and thus far thier has been none during execution.